# Vectorizing a solr index with mahout using lucene.vector

Tags: mahout, amazon-emr

I'm trying to run a clustering job on Amazon EMR using Mahout.
I have a solr index that I uploaded on S3 and I want to vectorize it using mahouts lucene.vector.(this is the first step in the job flow)

The parameters for the step are:

- Jar: s3n://mahout-bucket/jars/mahout-core-0.6-job.jar
- MainClass: org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver
- Args: lucene.vector --dir s3n://mahout-input/solr_index/ --field name --dictOut /test/solr-dict-out/dict.txt --output /test/solr-vectors-out/vectors

The error in the log is:

> Unknown program 'lucene.vector' chosen.

I've done the same process locally with hadoop and Mahout and it worked fine. 
How should I call the lucene.vector function on EMR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've eventually figured out the answer. The problem was I was using the wrong MainClass argument. Instead of

```
org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver
```

I should have used:

```
org.apache.mahout.utils.vectors.lucene.Driver
```

Therefore the correct arguments should have been

- Jar: s3n://mahout-bucket/jars/mahout-core-0.6-job.jar MainClass:
- org.apache.mahout.utils.vectors.lucene.Driver
- Args: --dir s3n://mahout-input/solr_index/ --field name --dictOut  /test/solr-dict-out/dict.txt --output /test/solr-vectors-out/vectors

Answer (score 0):

program name, lucene.vector should be immediately after bin/mahout

/homes/cuneyt/trunk/bin/mahout  lucene.vector --dir /homes/cuneyt/lucene/index --field 0 --output lda/vector --dictOut /homes/cuneyt/lda/dict.txt

Comment: Since I'm running this on Amazons Elastic MapReduce as a custom jar jobflow, I can only use the jar files from mahout. I've figured out the problem and posted an answer